# Calculate PHP HMAC SHA1 key for an API from C# code

Tags: c#, php, api, hmacsha1

## The Problem

I am trying to replicate the following C# code in PHP. It is example code for an API, which I need to interface with using PHP5.

```
string key = "9c132d31-6a30-4cac-8d8b-8a1970834799";
int developerId = 2;
string url = "/v2/mode/2/line/787/stops-for-line";

// add developer id
url = string.Format("{0}{1}devid={2}",url,url.Contains("?") ? "&" : "?",developerId);
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
// encode key
byte[] keyBytes = encoding.GetBytes(key);
// encode url
byte[] urlBytes = encoding.GetBytes(url);
byte[] tokenBytes = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(keyBytes).ComputeHash(urlBytes);
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
// convert signature to string
Array.ForEach<byte>(tokenBytes, x => sb.Append (x.ToString("X2")));
// add signature to url
url = string.Format("{0}&signature={1}",url,sb.ToString());

// extra code to add base URL – the resultant url should be:
//  base URL . /v2/mode/2/line/787/stops-for-line?devid=2&signature=D5474F344CDAA7B92F2253169F6C1D66C1A15001
```

What I take from this is that `hmac_hash('sha1','/v2/mode/2/line/787/stops-for-line?devid=2','/v2/mode/2/line/787/stops-for-line?devid=2')` needs to output `D5474F344CDAA7B92F2253169F6C1D66C1A15001`.

## Attempted Solution

Having read through the code, I couldn't spot anything obvious that might suggest a non-standard hashing routine, so I've gone with this:

```
$devID = 2;
$key = '9c132d31-6a30-4cac-8d8b-8a1970834799';
$url = '/v2/mode/2/line/787/stops-for-line?devid=' . $devID;

$my_sign = hash_hmac('sha1', $url, $key, false);
```

However, this gives `1fd3ac2ec7fe0ea39d7d5ef44a23b89aa7974b41` as the hash, which is obviously not right. I've read that base64 decoding the key and encoding the resultant hash can sometimes be the trick, but sadly that's not the case. Any resources you can point me to or code example would be greatly appreciated.